# Ten parabolas are drawn in a plane.No three parabola are concurrent. Find the total number of disjoint regions of the plane.

Tags: combinatorics

Ten parabolas are drawn in a plane. Any two parabola intersect in two real, and distinct, points. No three parabola are concurrent. Find the total number of disjoint regions of the plane.

I counted the number of regions for 1,2 and 3 parabolas and got 2, 5 and 10 regions respectively. I tried forming a recurrence relation but could not come up with anything.

Comment: Try to use V-E+F=2. You know that any two parabolas intersect into 4 points. You can count the edges, and then you can compute the number of regions as $F=E-V+2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R(n)$ be the number of regions formed by $n$ parabolas. If there are $n-1$ parabolas, the $n$th parabola will be intersected at $2(n-1)$ points, so it will be divided into $2n - 1$ parabolic arcs. Each arc adds one region (even if there is more than one arc in an existing region), so $R(n) = R(n-1) + 2n - 1$. Using $R(1) = 2$, it is simple to see that $\boxed{R(n) = n^{2} + 1}$.